# Concurrency issue. Optimizations change the order of the instructions

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

While i was reading the *"Seven Concurrency Models in Seven Weeks"* book i found the following notes for one example in Java language.

> - The compiler is allowed to statically optimize your code by reordering things.
> - The JVM is allowed to dynamically optimize your code by reordering things.
> - The hardware you’re running on is allowed to optimize performance by reordering things.

The past notes are serious words. The fact that the order of the instructions is not respected can could generate hard bugs in concurrency problems(I show the example of the book at the end), but this apply in others languages like C++ or Python?, i don't remeber seeing some warning about this in other languages but the third note(The hardware you’re running on is allowed to optimize performance by reordering things) covers everything.

So, is it correct to take care about this in all languages?

This notes are referred to the exercise.

```java
public class Puzzle {
 static boolean answerReady = false;
 static int answer = 0;

 static Thread t1 = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
   answer = 42;
   answerReady = true;
  }
 };

 static Thread t2 = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
   if (answerReady)
    System.out.println("The meaning of life is: " + answer);
   else
    System.out.println("I don't know the answer");
  }
 };

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  t1.start(); t2.start();
  t1.join(); t2.join();
 }
}
```

The problem is with the output in the second thread:

```java
The meaning of life is: 0
```

Because the instructions of the first thread is changed.

```java
   answer = 42;
   answerReady = true;
```

Comment: I recommend reading up on [Out-of-order execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution); it's entirely different than starting two threads, each of which is able to complete before the other (due to the lack of external synchronization). Your `answerReady` and `answer` variables also aren't `volatile`, so each thread may be caching its own state.

Comment: Not sure about python, but in C++ the compiler is allowed to completely change your code as long as the observable behaviour is equivalent.

Comment: Every language has a memory model describing how this behavior is to be handled. In general, operations can be reorganized so that the effects are undetectable within that thread, but when there are multiple threads, explicit synchronization is used to establish a happened-before relationship that says "everything happened before this point is now visible to other threads".

Comment: C/C++ don't have memory models, you get memory semantics by using a library (usually pthreads).  Python's memory model is to use a global interpreter lock, so that everything has single thread semantics (but you get no concurrency).  Java is fairly unique that it actually has a memory model built into the language spec.  (And the poster who said that you didn't use `volatile` is correct, you need to specify the memory semantics or the compiler can pretty much do as it pleases.)

Comment: @markspace, c/c++ don't have memory models is not a correct statement. They have volatile variables and their behavior is well-defined. Beyond that, the memory model for concurrent applications is that there are no guarantees on the effects of executions seen from another thread.

Comment: @markspace https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thanks for that correction (and to Jesper for the link).  I should read up.  To defend myself, my copy of the C++ language reference doesn't have a memory model.  I'm curious now when that was added to the language.

Comment: @markspace, all languages have a memory model, it is the rules and assumptions that define how the language runtime sees the memory and the effects of the program on the memory. Some are explicitly stated. For c/c++, I haven't seen one until today.

Comment: @BurakSerdar  I haven't seen one before either, and before about the year 2000 I thought the C/C++ memory model was whatever the hardware you ran on.  In other words the language itself didn't have a memory model, it relied on the CPU/system to supply the memory model.

Comment: I think, reordering by hardware has the smallest impact of all. Think about simple optimizations, e.g. `a++; b++; a++;`. Is the compiler allowed to do the obviously more efficient `a+=2; b++;` (or `b++; a+=2;`)? Either variant has the perceivable effect of reordering the `b++` with the first or the second `a++;`. Or something like `x = 0; /* unrelated code */ if(x == 0) { … }`; is the compiler allowed to presume the condition to be fulfilled or must it reread the value?